# How to log nginx vhost bandwidth?

Tags: web-server, nginx, bandwidth

I'm looking for a way to be able to track the bandwidth of multiple vhosts on an nginx web server.  I'm guessing there is a way that I can set up the log files to output this information and then I can write a script to parse through the log files and add up the file sizes.

If that is the case does anyone know the correct log format, and if there is already a script out there that does this?

Answer (score 1):

You can define new logs and their format using [ngx_http_log_module](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpLogModule). You can use the following commands in `http`, `server` or  `location` sections:

`log_format name format [format ...]` defines the format of the new log. Variable `$bytes_sent` will add the number of bytes sent for every request, including the length of HTTP headers.

`access_log path [format [buffer=size]]` specifies log-files. You can run this command for every vhost to define a separate log for every vhost.

Comment: Does this work with nginx-rtmp module?

Comment: @Ben , I don't think so, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) [plugin](http://exchange.munin-monitoring.org/plugins/nginx_vhost_traffic/details) that does exactly what you want - filters by specific vhosts and graphs it.